# Get a whole dataframe for every different value in a list

Tags: python

I currently have a list of ids and a dataframe with two columns.

```
list = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']

df =    A   B
    0   A1  B1
    1   A2  B2
    2   A3  B3
```

I would like to get a dataframe with the columns A and B from df for every value in the list.

Example:

```
    id  A   B
0   id1 A1  B1
1   id1 A2  B2
2   id1 A3  B3
3   id2 A1  B1
4   id2 A2  B2
5   id2 A3  B3
6   id3 A1  B1
7   id3 A2  B2
8   id3 A3  B3
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you try anything? did you look up how to concatenate dataframes? did you look up how to create new columns? are you familiar with `for` loops in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try with `pandas.concat`:

```
lst = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]

>>> pd.concat({l: df for l in lst}).droplevel(1).reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "id"})

     id   A   B
0   id1  A1  B1
1   id1  A2  B2
2   id1  A3  B3
3   id2  A1  B1
4   id2  A2  B2
5   id2  A3  B3
6   id3  A1  B1
7   id3  A2  B2
8   id3  A3  B3
```

Or with `pandas.concat` and `numpy.repeat`:

```
import numpy as np

>>> pd.concat([df]*len(lst),ignore_index=True).assign(id=np.repeat(lst, df.shape[0]))

    A   B   id
0  A1  B1  id1
1  A2  B2  id1
2  A3  B3  id1
3  A1  B1  id2
4  A2  B2  id2
5  A3  B3  id2
6  A1  B1  id3
7  A2  B2  id3
8  A3  B3  id3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works when the lenght of the list is the same as the number of rows of the dataframe. If the list has a 4th id I get the error: Length mismatch: Expected 12 rows, received array of length 16

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. The code should be pd.concat([df]*len(lst)).set_index(np.repeat(lst, len(df))). Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["A1", "A2", "A3"], "B": ["B1", "B2", "B3"]})
df_id = pd.DataFrame(["id1", "id2", "id3"], columns=["id"])
df_id["key"] = 1
df["key"] = 1
```

Then merge on the key:

```
df = df.merge(df_id, on="key").drop(["key"], axis=1)
```

You get :

```
Output:  
    A   B   id
0   A1  B1  id1
1   A1  B1  id2
2   A1  B1  id3
3   A2  B2  id1
4   A2  B2  id2
5   A2  B2  id3
6   A3  B3  id1
7   A3  B3  id2
8   A3  B3  id3
```